# Can someone explain what Process Enviornement Block (PEB), PCB (Process Control Block) and Thread Control Block (TCB) with an example how it work

Tags: windows, multithreading, process, operating-system

I have hard time to unnderstand PEB,PCB and TCB with respect to process and memory allocation. Can someone please explain with an actual example.

Comment: Can you at least make an effort to properly write the words of your question?

Comment: They are structs of state data for those elements.  Further details are too broad for an SO question.

Answer (score 1):

These are all data structures used by the Windows process manager. The Process Environment Block contains data that is relevant to the process itself, and hence can be read by applications. The process control block contains data that is only useful to the kernel, such as the preferred CPU for this process. The Thread Control Block is entirely different, and is what the kernel uses to manage threads, which are what the kernel runs at the lowest level.

Comment: A Great Succinct answer!